# Do I need a Tree Nursery for a Sawmill if I already have a natural forest?

Tags: anno-2070

In campaign mission 1-4, I need to supply wood for an item as one of my quests. In order to do this, I need to build a Sawmill. The production chain ingame recommends a Tree Nursery for a Sawmill, but I'm wondering how necessary it is to have a Tree Nursery if I'm placing the Sawmill in an area that is currently fully forested.

Will there be a negative effect on my Sawmill's productivity if I don't build a Tree Nursery for it? What bonuses will I get if I *do* choose to build a Tree Nursery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Anno 1404, the sawmill doesn't replenish the trees it cuts down. The tree nursery replenishes trees. If you build your sawmill in a fully forested area, eventually it'll use all the trees it has in its surrounding and then will not be able to cut down any more trees, because there won't be any.

If you just want to build a sawmill, deforest the area, and then demolish it and move on, you don't need a tree nursery, if you want to create a supply chain that will continue to produce wood, you need to build a Tree Nursery.

Take notice that 1 Tree Nursery can support several sawmill, see layout [here](http://anno2070.wikia.com/index.php?title=Eco_Production_Layouts&image=Wood_ecos-png).